# How would I split an index into a multi-index as follows?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a large excel file with thousands of rows and about 100 columns.  The problem is that the index column includes about 50 metrics (Sales, Houses, People) and 70 companies.  What I really want is to have two indexes one for metrics and one for the companies.  consider the following code as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx=['Sales','Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3','Houses','Company 1',     
'Company 2', 'Company 3','People','Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3']
dt=['2010','2011','2012','2013']
data = np.array([np.arange(12)]*4).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=dt)
df.iloc[4,::]=0;df.iloc[8,::]=0 
df
```

the result looks like the attached image 
[image]

my question is how would I manipulate the dataframe so the first index would be Sales, Sales, Sales....while the second index would be Company 1, Company 2, Company 3 for each metric (Sales, Houses etc.)?

Comment: Do the number of companies stay the same between each metric?

Comment: Yes they do.  Fixed number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
c = 3 # number of companies
metrics = df.index[::c+1]
companies = df.index[1:c+1]
```

---

This answer simply takes the metrics, finds the companies, creates a `MultiIndex` and reassigns.  It operates on one assumption:  **companies are in the same order in between each metric**:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([metrics, companies])
df.drop(df.index[::c+1]).set_index(idx)
```

```
                  2010  2011  2012  2013
Sales  Company 1     1     1     1     1
       Company 2     2     2     2     2
       Company 3     3     3     3     3
Houses Company 1     5     5     5     5
       Company 2     6     6     6     6
       Company 3     7     7     7     7
People Company 1     9     9     9     9
       Company 2    10    10    10    10
       Company 3    11    11    11    11
```

---

If you can't guarantee this constraint, it gets a bit trickier:

```
u = pd.Series(df.index)
idx = u.groupby(u.index // (c + 1)).transform('first') + '|' + u
f = df.drop(df.index[::c+1])
f[['metric', 'company']] = (idx.drop(idx.index[::c+1])
                               .str.split('|', expand=True).set_index(f.index))    
f.set_index(['metric', 'company'])
```

```
                  2010  2011  2012  2013
metric company
Sales  Company 1     1     1     1     1
       Company 2     2     2     2     2
       Company 3     3     3     3     3
Houses Company 1     5     5     5     5
       Company 2     6     6     6     6
       Company 3     7     7     7     7
People Company 1     9     9     9     9
       Company 2    10    10    10    10
       Company 3    11    11    11    11
```